# Micropython и atmega328p-pu

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, микроконтроллеры, micropython

Возможно ли установить micropython на ардуиновский микроконтроллер atmega328p-pu?

Comment: Нет, для micropython нужен более мощный микроконтроллер, и довольно много памяти. Нужно что-то типа ESP8266, ESP32, STM32.

Comment: на esp32 у меня уже установлен микропитон, просто хотел с ардуинки

Comment: Нет, с ардуинки не получится.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю для интерпритаторов на ардуинке слишком мало памяти и в целом для этого они слабоваты. Если на  ESP32 уже ставил, посмотри в сторону BlackPill, думаю сойдёт и с контроллером  STM32F401CCU6. Интерпритатор Java Script тутда ставил (но на С++ всё же лучше), но  Micropython возможно тоже потянет.

Comment: **ИнтерпрЕтатор**.